# why it says undefinedColumn when the column actually exist when I run postgres sql in Python?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am getting table from postgres database through python.
It keeps telling me the column does not exist, but actually it exists.
Could someone tell me what I have done wrong?

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7zpj.png)[This is the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQi4y.png)

I want to know how can I get the table I want

Here is the code:
pd.read_sql_query("select * from lines where cust_id = 22120",con = engine)

Comment: The column's name is `Cust_ID` in the database, not `cust_id` as in the query. The column name was identified as `"Cust_ID"` when it was defined. Enclosng the name in double-quotes made the name case sensitive. The error message identifies the issue when it says `Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "lines.Cust_ID"`.

Comment: In future, please post details as readable text instead of links to images.

Comment: pd.read_sql_query('select * from lines where "Cust_id" = 22120',con = engine)

You mean like above? It is still not working

Comment: Sure, I will. I cannot post image yet since I am new in stackoverflow

Comment: It must be `"Cust_ID"`, not `"Cust_id"`.

Comment: May I ask one more question? I have another table and the table also have the column named Cust_ID. But I don't need a double_quotes to run the query. Why I need a double-quote here?

Comment: Because I bet when you look at the table in `psql` it is actually `cust_id`.

Comment: So, if a column name has a capital letter then the double-quote is needed, if a column name does not have any capital letter, we do not need double-quote. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually not that simple. See [Identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS). Also try to stay away from using [Key words](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Read the section for more detail.